# APDU command read contact smart card id data

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I have a contact smart card reader following `ISO-7816` standard and I have a smart card id with ATR:

```
3B 7F 96 00 00 80 31 80 65 55 85 03 00 EF 12 41 40 82 90 00
```

My goal is to get the data saved to card like civil id number, DOB etc so I tried to select the MF file using the following command:

```
APDU: 00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00 

RAPDU: 6F 1C 83 02 3F 00 8C 03 06 E4 E4 9C 03 06 E4 E4 84 0C A0 00 00 00 18 40 00 00 01 63 42 00 90 00
```

as I read that commands is executed successfully as it returns `9000` as SW1 SW2 fields and I know the part of the returned message before the 9000 is data but my problem here that I don't know what is data represent or how to use this data to get the id stored information that I need.

Comment: you should read ISO-7816 part 4 document.

Comment: Without substantial documentation as e.g. specification of the card, description of file structure (if there are files), card supplier manual etc. success will be limited. Smart cards are designed to securely keep information, and if the card is designed to disclose the information only after some authorization, you are out of luck.